# Why is my echo command behaving like this?

Tags: bash, echo

I'm new to bash scripting and I'm asking for a little help ! 
I've got a little scipt in bash that is not making what I want (but almost) and the behavior of my echo command seems strange to me, look at it :

```
TST='test'
TEST="${ADDR[3]}"_"$TST"
echo $TEST
#result : _test
echo ${ADDR[3]}
#result : 5
```

How can you explain these results ? Thanks in advance :)

My ADDR var is defined like this :

```
#parsing the read line, split on whitespace
IFS=' ' read -ra ADDR <<< "$line"
```

Here is my complete script :

```
#!/bin/bash
NUMBER=2
{ read ;
while IFS= read -r line; do
echo "$NUMBER : $line"
IFS=' ' read -ra ADDR <<< "$line"
#If the countdown is set to 0, launch the task ans set it to init value
if [ ${ADDR[0]} == '0' ]; then
    #task launching
    echo `./${ADDR[1]}.sh ${ADDR[2]} &` 
    TST='test'
    TEST=${ADDR[3]}_$TST
    echo $TEST
    VAR=$(echo -E "${ADDR[3]}" | tr -d '\n')
    #countdown set to init value
    sed -i "$NUMBER c $VAR ${ADDR[1]} ${ADDR[2]} ${ADDR[3]}" listing.txt
else  
    sed -i "$NUMBER c $((ADDR-1)) ${ADDR[1]} ${ADDR[2]} ${ADDR[3]}" listing.txt
fi
((NUMBER++))
done } < listing.txt
```

Comment: Try `TEST=${ADDR[3]}_${TST}`.

Comment: The result is the same ...

Comment: Can you show where you define ADDR.  Your code looks fine.

Comment: @Ko2r really!!..i only give you second trick. but your code also work.

Comment: And what is `$line` set to?  It all looks ok so far.

Comment: Are there DOS carriage returns in `$line`?

Comment: Hum maybe ... that's what I'm trying to determine with the string concatenation ! I need this ADDR[3] to be without carriage return !

Comment: look at output of     hd <<< "$TEST"

Comment: I just changed my tr -d '\n' by tr -d '\r' and echo is behaving normal with the $VAR and $TST concatenation ! The problem is due to carriage return but how can you explaint the fact that the ADDR[3] isn't displayed ... For me it should be displayed with a new line between variables, isn't it ?

Comment: it is displayed - but overwritten then. carriage return alone doesn't advance to next line.

Comment: The sane way to get rid of CRs once and for all is `tr -d '\015' <listing.txt | { read; ... }`

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for the tip, indeed it's better !!

Answer (score -4):

Answer: the following is fine,

```
TEST="${ADDR[3]}"_"$TST"
```

Although I would recommend.

```
TEST="${ADDR[3]}_${TST}"
```

What you need to do is dump `${ADDR[3]}` before this statement and confirm that `ADDR` holds the expected values. You may as well dump the entire array with indexes and confirm all entries

```
for ((i=0; i<${#ADDR[@]}; i++)); do
    printf "ADDR[%3d] %s\n" "$i" "${ADDR[$i]}"
done
```

This will help isolate the issue. Sorry for the earlier answer. Lesson [sleep 1st: answer 2nd]

Comment: -1 This is entirely incorrect. The quotes will be gone by the time the actual assignment occurs. It is fine to have an unquoted underscore between quoted strings.

Comment: That's true, the real problem occurs because of the CR symbol which causes overwritten like Bushmills said !